# Not able to connect to SQlitedb properly using Spring data jpa

Tags: sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I have tried many possible solutions but nothing seems to work, I think I am missing something small but important. Seeing so many solutions now I am confused. Is it a problem establishing db connection or with jar version? I am using sqlite for the first time.
I have used transformer, tried modifying scope of jar, versions , came across a solution where it mentioned something about repository of sqlite-jdbc but didn't understand it fully.
Please help.
I am getting the following error
 https://pastebin.com/E0ND6WYL
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.epsilon.bike</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-1</name>
    <description>BIke project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zsoltfabok/sqlite- 
    dialect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>

Application.properties




    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    spring.jpa.ddl-auto=none
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:bike.db
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
    #spring.datasource.username=
    #spring.datasource.password=
```

Comment: Please define "not able to connect": are you getting an error? If so what is it? Or is something else happening. Please *edit the question*.

Comment: I edited, the stacktrace is in the pastebin link.